# How do I return my original list on the 3rd click?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, frontend, backend

Front end code

```
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
//sort function final
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [sortedCustomerList, setSortedCustomerList] = useState([]);

  function sortCustomer() {
    const sortedCustomer = [...customerList];
    let sortCount = counter;
    //check the current sortCount, if it is 3 then go back to 1, if not then increase by 1
    if (sortCount === 3) {
      sortCount = 1;
      setCounter(1);
    } else {
      sortCount += 1;
      setCounter(sortCount);
    }
    console.log(sortCount);
    if (sortCount < 3) {
      sortedCustomer.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (sortCount === 1) {
          return x.contacted === y.contacted
            ? 0
            : x.contacted === "Yes"
            ? -1
            : 1;
        } else if (sortCount === 2) {
          return x.contacted === y.contacted
            ? 0
            : x.contacted === "Yes"
            ? 1
            : -1;
        }
      });

      setCustomerList(sortedCustomer);
    } else {
      setCustomerList(customerList);
    }
  }
<th onClick={() => sortCustomer()}>Contacted?</th>
```

I have implemented a sort function onClick method. So first click returns the descending order list, 2nd click returns the ascending order list but the 3rd click does not return the original customerList. how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
const [sortedCustomerList, setSortedCustomerList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
        setCustomerList(response.data);
        setSortedCustomerList(response.data);
    });
}, []);

function sortCustomer() {
    const sortedCustomer = [...customerList];
    let sortCount = counter;
    if (sortCount === 3) {
        sortCount = 1;
        setCounter(1);
    } else {
        sortCount += 1;
        setCounter(sortCount);
    }

    if (sortCount < 3) {
        sortedCustomer.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (sortCount === 1) {
            return x.contacted === y.contacted
            ? 0
            : x.contacted === "Yes"
            ? -1
            : 1;
        } else if (sortCount === 2) {
            return x.contacted === y.contacted
            ? 0
            : x.contacted === "Yes"
            ? 1
            : -1;
        }
        });
        setSortedCustomerList(sortedCustomer);
    } else {
        setSortedCustomerList(customerList);
    }
}

Use sortedCustomerList to print on the screen

<th onClick={() => sortCustomer()}>Contacted?</th>
```

Comment: from where are you getting customerList?

Comment: I edited my code to show where I get customerList

Comment: try changing back  `if (sortCount < 3) ` You changed to code

Comment: Hello I changed it back but still the 3rd click which I console logged does not return original customer list

Comment: ` setCustomerList(sortedCustomer);
    } else {
      setCustomerList(customerList);
    }`

    Change setCustomerList to setSortedCustomerList and don't update in the question, try this in your local

Comment: Could you edit your post to show the code? If I were to change both setCustomerList to setSortedCustomerList, my first and second clicks don't work anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233406/discussion-between-max-and-rahul-sharma).